# Improved design of selecting from large list of employees

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Currently we have "dueling" select lists where you can select multiple employees from `Available Employees` select box and transfer to `Assigned` select box.

Everything works fine most of the time, but one customer complained that it was taking up to 20 seconds to render the page.  Upon inspection, they had 3000 employees so there were 3000 options in the select box and that was a major culprit to the long load time.

Any ideas of better design of this?  I've considered alphabetic paging, but with a width of 200px, it may look odd with the letters scrunched below.

Any ready made solutions out there? Suggestions?

Comment: How about a LinkedIn style Alpha paging (Vertical with some JQuery scolling effects)?  Good to use in limited width situations (might take up 20px or so)

Comment: .Net.  We're actually using Maverick .net (precursor to mvc).

Comment: @Tommy - Good idea, the only thing with the LinkedIn solution is that they are still listing all the employees and then scrolling down to the character requested.  If I could truly page it somehow would perform better.

Comment: That's true, but you could implement where you just go fetch employees starting with the letter clicked instead of doing a full loading of all employees.  Would be the same principle as numeric paging but instead of using .Skip(n).Take(x) -> your function would be something like .Where(x=>x.Name.StartsWith(LetterParameter)

Comment: @Tommy - Yeah, I like it more and more. The <ul> modal popup filter is pretty cool.  Would be a bit of work but probably worth the effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an alphabetic index that selects the list of employees that appear in the "Available" list. That should narrow it down enough in this case to speed things up. Grab the resulting list via AJAX.

This question isn't about code per se, so it really belongs on: https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like what I was thinking as well.  Are there any ready made pagers out there?  I guess it would be pretty quick to build from scratch as well.  JQuery solutions?

Comment: Went with the alphabet list, default it to "A" on page load.  Works great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) textbox, like the jQuery one.  When they select the employee name, you can then add it to the Assigned box.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I've thought of that one as well.  From what I hear over here it sounds like the users would prefer an alphabet pager.  Do you have any examples of how that would look and work?